# Python Virtualenv mostrando libs do computador

Tags: python, virtualenv

boa noite.
(Uso Ubuntu)
Eu estou mexendo com flask com alguns colegas e usamos o Virtualenv para criar ambientes virtuais. O meu problema é o seguinte:
Sempre que eu dou pull em algo do github e já vem a pasta do ambiente virtual, quando eu tento executar diz que as libs que a gente da import nos arquivos não existem. Porém, eu já chequei e elas estão dentro da pasta.
Quando eu entro no ambiente virtual que dei pull pelo terminal e dou o comando pip3 freeze, mostra as mesmas bibliotecas q quando eu dou o comando fora do ambiente virtual.
O ambiente virtual só funciona como o esperado quando eu mesmo crio e instalo as libs.
Eu estou suspeitando que seja pelo fato de eu usar linux e os outros membros do projeto usarem windows, isso interfere em algo? Não consegui encontrar nada a respeito.
Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Bom - o principal problema é que o virtualenv *nunca* deveria estar junto com os outros arquivos versionados no GIT.
O que precisa estar no git é o arquivo que lista as dependencias - em geral o requirements.txt (mas há outros tipos de arquivo que tem o mesmo papel, o mais moderno sendo o "Pipfile" do projeto "pyenv", mas também "buildout", oou o próprio "setup.py" pode conter todas as dependências).

Dentre os problemas de tentar versionar as próprias biblitoecas do virtualenv, um dos grandes (mas nunca o único), é que qualquer das bibliotecas que tenha um arquivo compilado em código nativo (isso é:  que não seja Python puro), não é, depois de instalada, "multi-sistema operacional"- ou seja, se instalaram, por exmplo, a lib "lxml" no Windows, os arquivos dela no virtualenv não são compatíveis com Linux.

Isso não tem a ver com o problema que você está relatando - maspode ter mais diferenças entre um virtualenv criado no windows, e outros em outros nos sistemas operacionais normais. (Quando se trata de ambiente de desenvolvimento, Windows é "o patinho feio", que usa regras diferentes de todo o resto do mundo - Linux, BSDs, MacOS, todos os sistemas Unix, que são usados em ambientes de nuvem, móveis, embarcados, etc...). Em particular, um virtualenv em geral é *fixo* no diretorio absoluto em que foi criado - tentar move-lo não funciona bem - e onde ele vai ficar no Linux forçosamente vai ter um nome diferente dos caminhos usados no Windows (o caminho não vai começar com "C:", por exemplo)

Então - vocẽ não conta como está "ativando" esse virtualenv, mas a chance é que ele não esteja ativo "at all". E se estivesse, um tanto das bibliotecas não iria funcionar, por conta da incompatibilidade entre binários.

## solução:

Remova o conteúdo do virtualenv do repositório GIT, crie um arquivo requirements.txt, e cada desenvolvedor cria o seu virtualenv na sua máquina - ajustado para o sistema em que está trabalhando, e na estrutura de diretórios presente.

Comment: Um extra, os desenvolvedores podem convencionar usarem o mesmo nome de diretório para guardar o ambiente virtual ("py3", "venv", etc) e colocarem este sujeito dentro do ".gitignore" para que isto nunca mais aconteça.